# What determines y-axis scaling on a normal probability plot?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, quantiles

I've been investigating Q-Q plots, specifically the normal probability plot, to determine if a set of data I have is approximately normal. I.e., a plot of the data should be approximately a straight line.

I am aware of the basic principles:

1. Sort the raw data
2. Find an approximation of the data to the means of the order statistics (rankit). I am personally using

$$ z_{i} = \frac{i - 0.3}{N + 0.4} $$

where $i$ is $i^{th}$ sample in the data and $N$ is the total number of samples (in my case, 200).

3. Plot the data and scale the tick-marks on the y-axis that the plotted points appear straight.

What I have trouble understanding is that third step. How do we determine what the scale of the y-axis/scale of the distances between ticks on the y-axis should be to ensure that the line is straight? I also don't understand why certain examples of probability plots have "evenly" spaced tick marks, whereas some others do not. For example,

[image]

this [MiniTab](https://www.minitab.com/en-us/) plot "squeezes" the distance between the middle probability values, [0.1 - 0.95] and "expands" the values that are at the extremes. However this SAS plot:

[image]

doesn't seem to change the interval on the y-axis nor scale distances between the ticks in any meaningful way. Yet both lines appear to be relatively straight. I could use some clarification on that third step. Is the inverse quantile function involved somehow?

If it makes a difference, I'm using d3.js to make my plot. This is what I have so far via arbitrary and manual scaling of the y-axis tick marks:

[image]

Comment: You skipped a step: you have to convert the $z_i$ (which are proportions in the interval $(0,1)$) into actual values by applying the standard Normal quantile function.  Then there's no need to rescale anything--but in this version of a QQ plot you *label* the vertical axis with the $z_i$ rather than with the corresponding quantile.

Comment: @whuber Ok, I see. But I have a question: After feeding my $z_{i}$ values into the quantile function $\Phi^{-1}(p) = \sqrt{2} \cdot {erf}^{-1}(2p-1)$ with the 5th order [inverse error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions), what do you mean by label the vertical axis with $z_{i}$? My new plot has the x values as the sample point and y values as the quantiles. I'm just not sure how to use the $z_{i}$ values for this to replicate Minitab.

Comment: The data we have described are triples $(x_i, z_i, u_i)$ where $x_i$ are the Calcium values, the $z_i$ are the *plotting points* you describe, and $\Phi(u_i)=z_i.$ You plot the $(x_i, u_i)$ pairs and you label the horizontal axis with the values of the first coordinate $x$  and you label the vertical axis with the values of $\Phi(u)$ rather than the second coordinate $u.$

Comment: That's a matter of figuring out the software, then.  In many plotting programs you can suppress the labeling of an axis and manually apply your own labels.

Comment: @whuber Right, I understand the methodology, but in practice, with d3.js, we have to define a scale for the y axis that goes the entire height of the plot. If we decide that scale should be using $u_{i}$ instead of $z_{i}$, then the labels also end up being those of $u_{i}$; $z_{i}$ won't work here. If it helps, a portion of the $u_{i}$ values end up being negative. How would these map back to the $[0, 1]$ interval?

Comment: I don't follow: the mapping between $u$ and $z$ is explicitly given by $\Phi,$ which results in values between $0$ and $1.$  The *original* scale (unlabeled) on the vertical axis gives the values of $u,$ whose range you can easily compute--you will find it is symmetrical around $0.$  There's no problem with negative values; half of them will be negative.  Again, *you plot $(x,u)$ and you use the $z$ values for labels.* It's that simple.  Search our site for threads on QQ plots and look at some.